# How to pass a props from one screen to another and display it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have to pass a data from one screen to another in reactjs. And to display the data on the receiver side.

I used a router to navigate between screen also passed data but couldn't display the received data.
The below code is where the data I passed.

```
<div onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/About', 
{ id:"2" })} class="col-sm-3 anchor">  

<img className="cat-img" src=""/>

<h3 className="text-center">name</h3>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the props using this following code in screen 2

```
{this.props.history.id}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the routing props in the other screen you have to use:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

But first, of course, you should a proper  component in your routing file with a path like:

```
<Route path="/your/path/:id" ... />
```

Comment: sorry, it's not showing the params. I'm trying to pass from one screen to another screen... It's from app.js to about.js. pls, help me out.

Comment: Then add your router configuration, app.js and about.js to your answer please.